# How make rouneded corners non-standarted?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need make demi-transparent border and rect ( where WHITE wrote ) with similar corners

like on MacOS X if you select file ( in Icon view in Finder ) with name in 2 or more rows.

How i need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CALayer) of a [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).  The `cornerRadius`, `borderColor`, and `borderWidth` properties of the `layer` of a `view` should do it for you.  Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
    containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2.5;
    containerView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.25 blue:0.25 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    [containerView release];
}
```

Dont forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of the `.m` file, or you can put it in your `-Prefix.pch` file if you use layers often.

Comment: No, this is not solving my task, if u under MacOS then make any folader with long string name ( must be in 2 rows ) and select ... i need like this: